# Minitest + Capybara: how to check if options list does not contain an option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

In my application i have a select tag containing some options:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select-course-js">
     <option>course-1</option> 
     <option>course-2</option>
     <option>course-3</option>
</select>
```

I would like to implement a system test that check if there is no course-4 option. Is it possible to do it with capybara? if so - how?
stack: rails5 + Minitest + Capybara

Update.
Solution (given by Thomas Walpole)

```
assert_no_select('select-course-js', with_options: ['course-4'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify there is no select 'select-course-js' on the page with `course-4` as an option via

```
assert_no_select('select-course-js', with_options: ['course-4'])
```

however that won't also verify that the `select-course-js` select is on the page, so you probably want to do both

```
assert_select('select-course-js')
assert_no_select('select-course-js', with_options: ['course-4'])
```

Another option would be to use the optional filter block

```
assert_select('select-course-js') do |el|
  el.has_no_selector?(:option, 'course-4')
end
```

but the error won't be as clear if the test fails.

Comment: Using the content of the option is a bit fragile IMO. It would break if they decided to change `'course-4'` to `'Course 4'`, for example.

Comment: @MarkMerritt possibly true - but it answers the question the OP asked which was to verify the option content wasn’t there

Comment: @MarkMerritt You are right. But in this case 'course-4' is auto-generated by business logic in other part of the system and will not be changed by users :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add id's to each `option` and check whether it exists...

```
<select class="form-control" id="select-course-js">
  <option id="crs-1">course-1</option> 
  <option id="crs-2">course-2</option>
  <option id="crs-3">course-3</option>
</select>
```

Then just check whether `crs-4` exists. The method you use will depend on your particular logic but here are a couple examples...

```
assert_no_css('#select-course-js #crs-4')
page.has_css?('#select-course-js #crs-4')
```

You can find other methods to use [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Minitest)

Comment: You need spaces between the ICSS Id selectors